# What's the difference between executing in terminal and executing a scriptfile via terminal?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

I'm getting different results running the following code inside the terminal vs. in a script file.

```
for i in {1..5}
do  
  echo $i is a number
done
```

Terminal output:

```
1 is a number
2 is a number
3 is a number
4 is a number
5 is a number
```

script output

```
{1..5} is a number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add :

```
#!/bin/bash
```

your default shell maybe sh, here is another example for sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
max=5
for i in `seq 1 $max`
do
    echo "$i" is a number
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, this is not really an answer, cause I do not able to name exact reason (not familiar with bash, just use it sometimes), but do not use #!/bin/sh, use #!/bin/bash for bash interpreter instead. There are some differences in syntax for bash and sh.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..5}
do  
  echo $i is a number
done
```

Got following output:

```
1 is a number
2 is a number
3 is a number
4 is a number
5 is a number
```